# Running commands on startup on a Red Hat server

Tags: rhel, boot, startup, services

I have a Red Hat server instance on AWS that I'm trying to make a nice AMI image of so I can test specific instance machine types with Apache Bench (`ab`).

I'm currently just trying to create the OS image with everything how I would like it. Currently I have httpd installed on the image. I want it so that when this image boots it automatically starts hosting its page.

Currently I'm starting the `httpd` service and stopping the `iptables` service to get the page to be served. Is there are way I can issue these commands on start up so that the page is served without having to SSH into the image and do it manually?

Answer (score 2):

Sure! You don't say but if you're using Red Hat Server (probably CentOS) and probably versions 5 or 6, all you have to do is configure the 2 services `httpd` and `iptables` so that they either startup or shutoff when your server boots.

#### Service setup

There is a command line tool which you can use to do this configuration change, called `chkconfig`.

```
$ chkconfig --level 345 httpd on
$ chkconfig iptables off
```

#### Leaving the firewall up

Rather than disable your firewall, I'd encourage you to simply leave it up and add a rule allowing the port 80 traffic in and out so that it can reach the Apache web server.

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

These rules should open up 80, assuming the Ethernet device your VM uses is `eth0`. You might need to do some sleuthing to get this information, you can use the `ip` command to confirm.

```
$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:52:00:ff:ff:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

#### Making the FW rules stick!

To make these `iptables` rules permanent you can add them as I've described above and then tell `iptables` to save them for next time.

```
$ /etc/init.d/iptables save
```

Comment: So the command `chkconfig --level 345 httpd on` will set the httpd to turn on when the login level is at 3, 4, or 5? // Also thanls, good answer, I think it will help!

Comment: @BumSkeeter - correct. This just sets it up so that it's configured. If you don't do a reboot and the service was off, it is still off after running this command. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Server-oriented RedHat Enterprise 6 (RHEL6) needs the file `/etc/rc3.d/S85httpd` when run in server mode to be a link to `/etc/init.d/httpd` and `/etc/rc3.d/S08iptables` be a link to `/etc/init.d/iptables`.  If, by chance, its inital runlevel is 5 (unlikely), the links would have the same names, but in the `/etc/rc5.d/` directory.

That in mind, as root I would:

```
cd /etc/rc3.d
ln -s ../init.d/httpd S85httpd
mv S08iptables K08iptables
cd /etc/rc5.d
ln -s ../init.d/httpd S85httpd
mv S08iptables K08iptables
```

To see the default run level in RHEL6:

```
grep initdefault /etc/inittab
```

Should this fail to start the services, one can add these lines to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

Running these commands starts up or shuts down services on the server.

Note that the next release of RedHat (RHEL7), which is already in beta and will almost certainly be out later this year, changes how files are started up at boot time using a technology which I feel makes managing daemons (services) a lot easier called `systemd` ... and uses a very different way of setting up services to start up at system boot time.

Comment: Yeah don't do it this way, this is bad! RH distros provide tooling for manipulating the S & K files in the various rc directories.

Comment: There are still a lot of RHEL/CentOS 5 machines out there which may not work with the chkconfig tools and what not.  I know RHEL5 -- which is supported for three more years -- has problems with `service foo start/stop` and needs to run `/etc/init.d/foo start/stop` instead

Comment: I've worked with RHEL3, 4, 5, & 6 in enterprise scenarios for most of my career and I've never encountered any issues w/ `chkconfig`. Not doubting that it doesn't happen but if it does, it's likely that a novice was attempting to admin the box w/o fully understanding the tools and left it in a broken state. `chkconfig` keys off of the header info in the scripts under init.d, so it also could be the case that the script wasn't "setup" for `chkconfig` too.

Comment: Yeah, I see a RPM file for `chkconfig` included with RHEL3, so it's been out there for a while (it's `service` that's new for RHEL6).  Anyway, it's going to be academic in a few years considering `systemd` does everything differently (albeit with a compatibility layer): http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SysVinit_to_Systemd_Cheatsheet

Comment: Yes all the knowledge will be relegated as useless 8-). I've been spending a fair amount of time getting experience with Systemd now in preparation.

Comment: I really ought to fire up a VM running a recent Fedora so I'm ready for the systemd shift (even though I'm a programmer who plays a sysadmin on TV instead of vice versa)

Comment: Same here, dev. 1st, admin 2nd. The 2 overlap so much that it's almost pointless to distinguish at times. I'm using Fedora 19 now, just upgraded from 14. It's an OS, nothing to get excited about, lots of things that I knew how they worked before, that have changed and so I'm acquiring new knowledge, it's the `while(1)` loop of working w/ computers.

Answer (score -4):

Changing habits is always painful, but after using it with the RHEL 7 Beta for one month, I can say, it's the way to go: http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-get-started-systemd/

Comment: It is better to provide the information here, and use the link as a reference for further details. That way your answer does not loose all of it value when the link becomes invalid.